# I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2 address=0x0) error when I try to type in textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a student who study both English and Objective-C from a far-away country.

The code below is test code that when I type something in textfield. then immediately print a char on command line.

But When I touch textfield on running app. An blurry error occurs.

```
#import "SimpleViewController.h"
#import "SimpleTextFieldDelegate.h"

@interface SimpleViewController ()

@end

@implementation SimpleViewController

@synthesize field;
@synthesize label;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   // Nothing special in here.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Do this will be printed on command line?");
    [self.field setDelegate: [[SimpleTextFieldDelegate alloc] init]];
}
```

@end

This is SimpleViewController class implementation code.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
                                                  <- error caused at here.
    }
}
```

Why I got this error? I couldn't grab any guess.

Comment: Try retaining the simpletextfielddelegate as a view @property in the interface

Comment: @JB13 the property code perfectly exists in interface code in "SimpleViewController.h", but the result is same.

Comment: It looks like. there is nothing special that could an cause error. I just initialized Delegate.., please help me..

Answer (score 1):

```
#import "SimpleViewController.h"
#import "SimpleTextFieldDelegate.h"

@interface SimpleViewController ()
@property SimpleTextFieldDelegate MySimpleTextFieldDelegate;
@end

@implementation SimpleViewController

@synthesize field;
@synthesize label;
@synthesize MySimpleTextFieldDelegate;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
```

// Nothing special in here.
    }

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

MySimpleTextFieldDelegate = [[SimpleTextFieldDelegate alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Do this will be printed on command line?");
[self.field setDelegate:MySimpleTextFieldDelegate];
}
```

Comment: After posting an answer, I realized that yours is virtually identical, so I'll delete mine. I'd encourage you, though, to add a little narrative explaining why the above technique works. I might also suggest (a) using property setter rather than ivar when instantiating the `SimpleTextFieldDelegate` object; and (b) adopting camelCase lowercase first letter for variable, per [Cocoa naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/codingguidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html), e.g. `simpleTextFieldDelegate` for variable. But +1!